# Why index reference does not working correct for variable placing in a list

Tags: python, list, class

I had been writing this code, so I expected that function from class, has been applied to the first and second variable from the list.

Imported files contains:
ch0.txt = 111,
ch1.txt = 123

Yet, only the ch1.txt is loaded, and it is set for all of variable from the list (sic!).

Could you explain me why indexing like this does not work, or how I can change code to load content of each file to another variable; in way:
s[i] = content of file ch[i].txt

```
class Test:
    name = "empty"

    def load(self, file_name):
        wczytanie = open(file_name, "r")
        dane = wczytanie.read().split("\n")

        self.name = dane[0]

pos = Test()

s = [pos, pos, pos]
print(s)

s[0].load("ch" + str(0) + ".txt")
s[1].load("ch" + str(1) + ".txt")

print(s)
print(s[0].name)
print(s[1].name)
```

The output:

```
[<__main__.Test object at 0x00000230771A40D0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x00000230771A40D0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x00000230771A40D0>]
[<__main__.Test object at 0x00000230771A40D0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x00000230771A40D0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x00000230771A40D0>]
123
123

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because all 3 indexes in your list `s` correspond to the same instance of `Test`, which is `pos`. When you set `s[0]`, you are actually setting `pos`, meaning that it changes `s[1]` and `s[2]` because they are also both `pos`. To fix this, try making a new instance of `Test` for each index.

Additionally, your `name` variable is a [*class variable*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) (in some languages called a *static variable*), meaning that when you run `self.name = dane[0]`, python actually creates a new *instance variable*. To fix this, initialize `self.name` in a `__init__` function (if you want it to stay as `empty` before loading) and remove the unneeded `name` *class variable*.

**NOTE:** You also should close the file `wczytanie` in your `load` function - otherwise, other applications will not be able to use it until your application ends.

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "empty"

    def load(self, file_name):
        wczytanie = open(file_name, "r")
        dane = wczytanie.read().split("\n")

        self.name = dane[0]
        wczytanie.close()

s = [Test(), Test(), Test()]
print(s)

s[0].load("ch" + str(0) + ".txt")
s[1].load("ch" + str(1) + ".txt")

print(s)
print(s[0].name)
print(s[1].name)
```

Output:

```
[<__main__.Test object at 0x000001B5716FBFD0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x000001B5716FBFA0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x000001B5716FBF10>]
[<__main__.Test object at 0x000001B5716FBFD0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x000001B5716FBFA0>, <__main__.Test object at 0x000001B5716FBF10>]
111
123
```

As one final side note, please don't name things like `dane`, `s`, or `wczytanie`, which have no real meaning without context. Either add context or name these more helpfully so you in the future will understand what they do, and other programmers will too.

Answer (score 1):

The indexing is working, however the `name` you reference is the same for every item in that list.

This is because you are defining the list with:

```py
pos = Test()
s = [pos, pos, pos]
```

instead of

```py
s = [Test(), Test(), Test()]
```

which means that it is actually the same object being referenced three times in that list, rather than three separate items.

Make sure you call `Test()` individually to get separate instances of that class.

---

On a side note, because you've defined the `name` field in the class definition, it is a Class Variable, rather than an Instance Variable.
This means that the `name` is shared between all instances of the `Test` class, even if you had created multiple instances.

Read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) for more info.

*Update: just tested and in this case it doesn't make an actual difference due to the way it's being assigned, but worth being aware of this pitfall)*

---

Another side note - for your file handling, always try to use a `with` block as this will automatically close the file for you after it has been read out of, allowing other programs to still access the file whilst your program is running:

```py
with open(file_name, "r") as wczytanie:
    dane = wczytanie.read().split("\n")
```

Comment: Your "Secondly" part is incorrect.  Yes, `name` is initially a class variable, but the assignment to `self.name` creates an instance variable that will be accessed from then on.  There's no problem with this.

Comment: Ah yeah good point, not particularly applicable here, I've just been aught out by that too often!